# How get the input value (date) from ng2-date-picker component in Angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to get the value from a date picker (ng2-date-picker) input field, but might be missing something. I have tried all sorts of different ways to get the value, but with little success.

This is the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-date-picker) to the npm package I am using.

**This is my date picker setup in my component:**

```
import { DatePickerComponent } from 'ng2-date-picker';

  @ViewChild('dayPicker', {static: false}) datePicker: DatePickerComponent;
  open() { this.datePicker.api.open(); }
  close() { this.datePicker.api.close(); }
```

**This is the date picker setup in my view:**

```
    <dp-date-picker
        #dayPicker
        name="dob"
        [(ngModel)]="dateOfBirth"
        [config]='dateConfig'>
    </dp-date-picker>
```

I have tried accessing the value using the reference - `#dayPicker` and ngModel using `dateOfBirth`, but both values are `undefined` even after a date has been selected.

```
console.log('DOB: ' + this.dateOfBirth); (undefined)
console.log('this.datePicker: ' + this.datePicker); (undefined)
```

The only way I have been able to access the value, was through the following (but this only updates on the `blur event`, so I only get a value after the 2nd time the date is changed).

```
this.datepickerInputValue = (<HTMLInputElement><any>document.getElementsByClassName('dp-picker-input'))[0].value;
console.log('input value: ' + this.datepickerInputValue);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any errors in he console when using `ngModel`?

Comment: Nope, I don't get any errors. Tried all variations of ngModel. But still get an undefined value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `(onChange)` or `(onSelect)` on your datepicker tag? If none of those 2 works try this `(ngModelChange)`. They should work btw.

Comment: How, and where would the OP make these changes?

Comment: what do you mean? OP?

Comment: I was able to get the required value using (ngModelChange)="dateOfBirthChange($event)". However, I'm still perplexed why ngModel and the reference does not work....

Comment: Yeah it happened with me as well quite a while back. They have mentioned in the documentation as well  " if you want to receive every value (valid and invalid) please use the native ngModelChange output. "

Comment: But I am glad it helped you solve the problem :). If you think it did mark it as an answer.

Comment: OP - Original Poster. Your post doesn't show how to do what you say should be done. Add some details/code. Make the post valuable!

Comment: Actually he already mentioned the link for the package and the documentation has output methods plus having these methods are output methods used on the tag in question but thanks for pointing it out :), I have updated the answer and added "on the datepicker tag" that is where `(relevant_method_name)` goes.